# Rails Friendly_id error when Field Blank

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have the friendly_id initializer to shorten the value if there is a duplicate value in the database.

```
# over writing the conflict slug
module FriendlyId
  module Slugged
    def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
      candidates.first + friendly_id_config.sequence_separator + SecureRandom.hex(3)
    end
  end
end
```

Am using this in the Company Model as follows

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :name, use: :slugged
```

Now if i leave the `name` blank and test the validation i am getting the following error

```
NoMethodError at /members

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass


Company#resolve_friendly_id_conflict
config/initializers/friendly_id.rb, line 5
```

Comment: what about setting up a default string if the name is blank?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method you changed was able to handle if there were no candidates but your method doesn't.

See the original code...

```
[candidates.first, SecureRandom.uuid].compact....
```

The compact would drop the nil value.

I'd suggest you convert the first candidate to a string to handle that case.

```
candidates.first.to_s + friendly_id_config.sequence_separator + SecureRandom.hex(3)
```

Even better, you can stick to the original pattern... just replace the random field with your own.

```
def resolve_friendly_id_conflict(candidates)
  [candidates.first, SecureRandom.hex(3)].compact.join(friendly_id_config.sequence_separator)
end
```